# Как перезаписывать файл и сохранять вывод обратно в файл?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Допустим у меня есть код

```
lines = f.readlines()
for line in lines:
    print(line.rstrip(), "=",eval(line))
f.close()
```

с таким выводом

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Вопрос : как перезаписать файл что бы оставался только вывод самого кода ? ? ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
lines = open('file', 'r', encoding='UTF-8').readlines()
open('file', 'w', encoding='UTF-8').write('\n'.join([f'{x.rstrip()} = {eval(x)}' for x in lines]))
```

Вы это имели ввиду?

Comment: Да,Спасибо огромное ,на галочку могу нажать только через 6 минут почему-то

Answer (score 0):

Можно ещё по-проще с сохранением Вашего кода:

```py
lines = f.readlines()
with open('file_to_write', 'w') as fp:  # <--
    for line in lines:  # <--
        print(line.rstrip(), "=",eval(line), file=fp)  # <--
f.close()
```